# API Error labels all over AWS management console (EC2 Dashboard)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ec2

After deploying a VPC using terraform, I get this:

[image]

What causes this / how can I debug this? the terraform `validate` always succeeds...
Often when I refresh the whole browser window, the issue is gone but not always?

Update even after it looks like the issue has cleared, sometimes I go to the instance level and I see: [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever user you're logged in as probably doesn't have sufficient permissions. This sometimes happens to me when I choose an incorrect region that we've disabled.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what it ended up being!

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so you can accept / close the question. If you have a better answer yourself please post it and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever user you're logged in as probably doesn't have sufficient permissions. This sometimes happens to me when I choose an incorrect region that we've disabled.