# API Errors on AWS management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am seeing these API Errors on the AWS management console (EC2 & VPC dashboards). Sometimes refreshing will allow it to work for a short time.
This only seems to happen when accessing from our company network, when accessing at home I do not see the issue, so I expect it is not a permission problem like this similar issue.
[API Error labels all over AWS management console (EC2 Dashboard)](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146733/api-error-labels-all-over-aws-management-console-ec2-dashboard)

When refreshing all of the menus and static content load quickly, but any of the dynamic information will take a long time and then show the errors.

[image]

[image]

[image]